# Person's ex sends a suggestive picture after they have been told not to

Tags: harassment, colorado

The person sent the message "No innuendos or pictures until further notice". Shortly thereafter he received a picture of private parts in tight clothing. Not long after that, he received a fully nude video of genitalia.

Isn't this sexual harassment? If so, what is the punishment for this in Colorado?

Comment: Added jurisdiction and generalized question

Comment: Are both parties aged 18 or over?

Comment: @Trish the question has been edited, and it no longer asks for legal advice.

Comment: "Sexual harrasment" is a term of art referring to employer-employee relations, a sub-type of sex discrimination (where federal and state law state which kinds of discrimination are illegal). The circumstances as you describe them suggest a terminated / suspended intimate relation, so criminal harrassment laws are inapplicable at least now. You need a restraining order (and a lawyer to deal with it).

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, nor do I live in the USA - so maybe someone else will have a better answer. Based on a whirlwind tour of Google I believe that this is not sexual harrasment (as it did not take place in  workplace).

I further believe it may be plain harassment as per Colorado Revised Statutes Title 18. Criminal Code § 18-9-111 -  The definition  states "(1) A person commits harassment if, with intent to harass, annoy, or alarm another person, he or she:"...
1(e) (e) Directly or indirectly initiates communication with a person or directs language toward another person, anonymously or otherwise, by telephone, telephone network, data network, text message, instant message, computer, computer network, computer system, or other interactive electronic medium in a manner intended to harass or threaten bodily injury or property damage, or makes any **comment, request, suggestion, or proposal by telephone, computer, computer network, computer system, or other interactive electronic medium that is obscene;**

The question is whether the images meet the threshold of being obscene - and I fear they dont - "(1.5) As used in this section, unless the context otherwise requires, “obscene” means a patently offensive description of ultimate sexual acts or solicitation to commit ultimate sexual acts, whether or not said ultimate sexual acts are normal or perverted, actual or simulated, including masturbation, cunnilingus, fellatio, anilingus, or excretory functions."

It would be a class 3 misdemeanor - (2) Harassment pursuant to subsection (1). This is the lowest tier  of "crime" - with a penalty of $50-$750 and / or up to 6 months in jail. If you look at other misdemeanors I suspect this would be at the low end even here.

If the behaviour worries you I imagine the appropriate course of action would be to block communication from this person and/or get a protective (restraining) order although your post implies the latter might be undesirable due to the "until further notice" statement in your post.